# Sending a value from a class to a form

Tags: c#, forms, class, label

What i'm trying to do is sending from a class a value to a label inside Form1.
Form1 is already running, so i can't say something like Form1.Show("value"); but i want something like this:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.label1.text = "Hello World"; //<-- i want to send this.
```

In VB is it this:

```
Form1.Label1.Text = "Hello World";
```

So can this be done in  a simple way? And without big code?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is probably a sign you are going down the wrong path.

That said, you can't do this because controls are private members. However, you *can* expose them through a property:

```
//Form1.cs
public Label SuperLabel { get { return label1; } }

...

//Other.cs
frm1.SuperLabel.Text = "Hello World";
```

Even better would be a method

```
//Form1.cs
public void SetSuperText(string text)
{
    label1.Text = text;
}

...

//Other.cs
frm1.SetSuperText("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property to your form, and use that property to set the form's label.

```
public string LabelText {
    get { return Label1.Text; }
    set { Label1.Text = value; }
}
```

And then from the class:

```
Form1.LabelText = "Hello World";
```

Answer (score 0):

in your label properties
set "Modifiers" to public

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method that has a return value like:

```
Public string SettingTheLabel()
{
   //something here
   return "LabelText";
}
```

Then set your label text on the containing form to the method

```
Label1.Text = SettingTheLabel();
```